# Unable to print to stdout

Tags: macos, go, macos-high-sierra, cgo

I'm able to get the program [here](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-Go_references_to_C) to print 42 as expected.

But I am unable to get the following program to print to stdout:

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
import "C"

import (
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    cs := C.CString("hello")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    C.fputs(cs, (*C.FILE)(C.stdout))
}
```

It runs without error, but it doesn't print anything. The above snippet is mostly based off the "Strings and things" code [here](https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo).

Comment: Why don't you check the return value of `C.fputs`? It may very well hint at the problem.

Comment: thanks: `./main.go:15: cannot convert nil to type _Ctype_int`

Comment: You mean you're doing something like `if C.fputs(...) != nil`? Then yeah C's `fputs` obviously does not return `nil` as C does not know anything about Go-style error handling. C's `fputs` retuns an `int`. Please read the manual page on `fputs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
package main

// #include <stdlib.h>
// #include <stdio.h>
import "C"
import "unsafe"

func main() {
    cs := C.CString("hello")
    defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(cs))
    C.puts(cs)
}
```

Explanation:

The `fputs` method writes a string to a data stream, in your case stdout, which is directed towards a pointer to a file that doesn't exist because it has neither been opened nor defined anywhere previously. So even though the program appears to execute without error, you aren't seeing any of the stdout because it is being redirected to a nonexistent file.

Further, it should be noted that simply dropping the code from the [Strings and things](https://blog.golang.org/c-go-cgo) section into a main program without some customization would not work because it is provided in the blog as a package, which is why there was confusion about the file existing. It seems that the `print` package from the blog post simply assumes the file you are attempting to write the data stream to has already been defined somewhere previously. It's a little confusing and they should probably adjust that.

I replaced `fputs` with `puts` as well as removed the pointer to the file and the program executes just fine.

Hope that even with the modifications this helps accomplish what you are looking for!

Comment: I'm not sure if your reasoning is correct but accepting because the code works.

Comment: That's kind of hide the problem instead of solve it.

Comment: Thank you for the constructive criticism to help me learn, and feel free to downvote but I was simply trying to provide an explanation of why the code that was being tried wasn't working and to provide a sample that still accomplished what the OP was looking for without getting too granular.

Comment: @waymobetta then did you explain why the part `(*C.FILE)(C.stdout)` doesn't work?

Comment: @leafbebop fair, I alluded to it with the first line about how stdout is being redirected to the file [that doesn't exist]. I could have explained in more depth about what he tried and why it didn't work. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

Another cause might be due to the fact you have the C *standard library* linked with your Go program, but the "standard I/O streams" (in the form of `FILE*`) is a property of the *C runtime,* and they have to be initialized before use.

For a typical program written in C, the compiler creates a special prologue code which actually runs before C's `main()` (usually to do that it links in a small object file standard for the target platform which does the necessary stuff and then jumps to `main`).

Supposedly in a Go program such initialization does not happen and so these high-level wrappers for the standard I/O streams left
uninitialized.

You might check if this is true by trying something like this:

```
f = fdopen(C.int(os.Stdout.Fd()), C.CString("w"))
C.fputs(cs, f)
```

and see if it works.

The `fdopen(3)` makes a `FILE*` object out of an OS-level
file descriptor for an already opened file,
and the `Fd()` function pulls just that out of a Go's `*os.File`.